# Systemd is never assigned pid 0 in container

Tags: docker, debian, dockerfile

I am trying to bring up continuous integration pipeline and that requires me to apt install an abc.deb file inside container.

The debian/control file do include:

```
Depends:  ${python3:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}, python3-webpy, systemd
```

The debian/rules file include(only relevant part showcased below):

```
%:
dh $@  --with=python3,systemd

override_dh_systemd_start:
    dh_systemd_start -p<application>

override_dh_installinit:
    dh_systemd_start
```

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM <relevant base image>
COPY results/*.deb /packages/
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  && apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --auto-remove \
    dumb-init \
    procps \
    /packages/*.deb && \
    apt-get autoremove -y && \
    apt-get autoclean -y && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /var/cache/apt
    CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

When I docker exec inside the docker and do ps aux, I get:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0   2388   756 ?        Ss   11:51   0:00 /bin/sh -c tail -f /dev/null
```

How can I have systemd as PID 1 ? ever per say dumb-init!

I tried looking to multiple articles, appears that it isn't possible, requires confirmation on same. The good ones are (to name few):

https://lwn.net/Articles/676831/

https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/

Comment: the PID 1 is alawys what you have in CMD

Comment: if you really need to have systemd in your container (I highly doubt that). You can set `/sbin/init` as your CMD or Entrypoint to start your container like a normal linux OS. Once again: **I do not recommend to start your container with `/sbin/init` or utilize systemd in your container.**

Comment: agree with @ClemensKaserer you should not use supervised, if still, you want to use the change Dockerfile ```VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]CMD ["/lib/systemd/systemd"]``` you can look https://github.com/j8r/dockerfiles/blob/master/systemd/ubuntu/16.04.Dockerfile, as your CMD is `tail command` so systemd will never get PID 1